# Shared Unit Tests with MSTest

Tags: unit-testing, inheritance, automated-tests, mstest, watin

I have approximately 5-6 reports, they are structured the same, using Watin, I'm testing each one of these reports.

I have a shared test, I call "ReportBaseTests"..

```
    public class ReportBaseTests
    {
        public string MenuName { get; set; }

        public ReportBaseTests(string name)
        { this.MenuName = name; }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Perform_Invalid_Date_Range()
        {
        }
    }
```

but in each of my tests, I have...

```
    [TestClass]
    public class Report1Tests : ReportBaseTests
    {
        public Report1Tests()
            : base("Report 1")
        { }
    }
```

This works... each report will have a seperate Perform_Invalid_date_range, and it'll goto a different page... I was hoping someone had a better way to do this, as it also produces a seperate "non-runnable" test for the shared test since I didn't include the [TestClass]

Now, I know I could use NUnit and pass in arguments, however, I'm sticking with MSTest for the time being

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted, you could add [TestContext support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404699.aspx) to your tests and have the ReportBaseTests.Perform_Invalid_Date_Range() parse the [TestContext.FullyQualifiedTestClassName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.fullyqualifiedtestclassname.aspx). For a simple test I think that's over kill.

For your solution: just put the `[TestClass]` attribute on `ReportBaseTests` and then mark `ReportBaseTests` as `abstract`. The "non-runnable" tests will disappear.

Comment: Appears this only works if you have the `[TestClass]` decorated classes in the same assembly as the base. Otherwise no tests show up in Test Explorer. :/